# Incorrect jQuery UI slider handle, advances from 2 directly to limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

My jQuery UI handle displays the number 14 correctly when loading the page, but if I set it a second time it moves the slider handle all the way to the end. Here's the sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/rRrgV/

Surely I've done something silly, right?

Comment: when defining a variable with js, and the variable is a JQuery selection, it is customary to name the variable starting with a single  '$'.  For example in your code,  var input should be var $input.

Comment: @chrisFrisina - that's unnecessary and unrelated to the solution.

Comment: really... why is that Chris? I don't prefix my variables with types, like var iNumber = 3; Also, can't some jQuery functions return a regular DOM element or a jQuery object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var v = input.val();
```

to:

```
var v = parseInt(input.val(),10);
```

Your `v` variable is a string so you need to convert it to an integer.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rRrgV/1/)**.